# useState is not working for material ui functional component(firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, material-ui

I am trying to make a sign up form where I am using a material ui functional component
I am trying to attach a signup event to the sign up button in "onClick"
now I am trying to pass email and password in useState() and then trying to console.log(email,password) but it returns nothing
console doesn't show errors either

```
   import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import {Route,} from "react-router-dom"
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import firebase from "firebase"



var Config ={ apiKey:"",
authDomain: "",
databaseURL: "",
projectId: "",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: "",
appId: ""

}

firebase.initializeApp(Config);
function signup(event){
const{email,password}=this.props;
   firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
   .then((user) => {
     // Signed in 
     // ...
     console.log(email,password)
     var err = "Welcome "+ user.email;
     firebase.database().ref('users/'+user.uid).set({email: user.email,password:user.password});
  
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     var errorCode = error.code;
     var errorMessage = error.message;
     // ..
     console.log(errorMessage)
   });
  }

function Copyright() {
    return (
      <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
        {'Copyright © '}
        <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
          Your Website
        </Link>{' '}
        {new Date().getFullYear()}
        {'.'}
      </Typography>
    );
  }

  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    avatar: {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    form: {
      width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
      marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    },
    submit: {
      margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    },
  }));
 
   
  export default function SignUp(props) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    
    const classes = useStyles();
      
    return (
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className={classes.paper}>
          <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
            <LockOutlinedIcon />
          </Avatar>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            Sign up
          </Typography>
          <form className={classes.form}  noValidate>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <input
                variant="outlined"
                margin="normal"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Email Address"
              
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setEmail(e.target.value);
                console.log(e.target.value)}}
                autoComplete="email"
                autoFocus
              />
              </Grid>
           
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <input
                  variant="outlined"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  name="password"
                  label="Password"
                  type="password"
                  id="password"
                  
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setPassword(e.target.value)
                    console.log(e.target.value);}}
                  autoComplete="current-password"
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={<Checkbox value="allowExtraEmails" color="primary" />}
                  label="I want to receive inspiration, marketing promotions and updates via email."
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              className={classes.submit}
              onClick={signup}
            >
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          
            <Grid container justify="flex-end">
              <Grid item>
                <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                  Already have an account? Sign in
                </Link>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </form>
        </div>
        
        <Box mt={5}>
          <Copyright />
        </Box>
      </Container>
     
    
    );
      }
```

any idea what's happening?

Comment: Most likely need to move your `signup` function inside your `SignUp` function. I would recommend re-naming one of those functions. You also have your `apiKey` and such exposed in the code you posted, I recommend removing those from the post.

Comment: It wasn't working when signup was inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues here:

1. You try to access email and password from `this.props` but you're keeping it as local state variables in your component.
2. Your `signup` method is outside of the scope of your functional component, as already mentioned in the comments. You can't access email and password here anyhow.

Move your function into the component function and remove this line `const{email,password}=this.props;` because email and password will then be available from the outer scope.